# Sql​Beautifier: How to change super+k super+f key binding?

Tags: sql, sublimetext3, sublimetext

For SQL formatting, I've installed [SqlBeautifier](https://packagecontrol.io/packages/SqlBeautifier) on Sublime Text.

I'm trying to change [SqlBeautifier](https://packagecontrol.io/packages/SqlBeautifier)'s key binding on macOS to something a bit simpler. Currently, it is <kbd>command</kbd>+<kbd>k</kbd> <kbd>command</kbd>+<kbd>f</kbd>:

```
{ "keys": ["super+k", "super+f"], "command": "sql_beautifier" }
```

I've added the above setting in `SQL Beautifier.sublime-settings` and have changed that. However, it does not enforce the changes.

How do I change that key binding? Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Key bindings do not go in `.sublime-settings` files they go in `.sublime-keymap` files.

Open your `User` `Default (OSX).sublime-keymap` file with:

```
Menu --> Preferences --> Key Bindings
```

Your `User` key bindings will be in the file on the right hand side.

Add your keys somewhere in that file:

```
{ "keys": ["super+k", "super+f"], "command": "sql_beautifier" }
```

The keys you show `"super+k", "super+f"` are the SQL Beautifier default keys so make sure you change them. The `Default` key bindings file, in the file on the left hand side, has many examples.